# WPF Image animation

Tags: wpf, image, animation

I have multi-threaded WPF aplication. There is small process in my application which runs in background and once it's done, UI will be updated with result.

I already implemented functionality and it's running perfectly fine. I just want to create animated processing image like below for my application so it will keep running until UI gets updated. I am not very good at Expression blend to create this kind of animation.

http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://www.sunvalleywellness.org/img/animation_processing.gif&imgrefurl=http://www.sunvalleywellness.org/&h=200&w=200&sz=55&tbnid=d4OPzhVnCB_kNM:&tbnh=90&tbnw=90&zoom=1&usg=__KPnWRjNlWm-AuZg0lavRE5lzMcA=&docid=JZavNcJukA3ZwM&sa=X&ei=SlenUcG-DIjtqwGMqYHAAQ&ved=0CDMQ9QEwAg&dur=733

Can you pls help me to create that. I

Thanks

Dee

Answer (score 0):

You must do it with a bool property in you View Model or DataContext. This property should indicate if are working in background, for example: `IsWorking`. When you start the job set this property true, when you finish the job, set it to false. See this sample code for you DataContext class:

```
var currentSyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
backgroundWorker.DoWork += (_,__) =>
                      {
                          currentSyncContext.Send((t)=>{IsWorking = true;},null);     //this is for change the visual tree from another thread
                          //Here write the job you want to do...
                          currentSyncContext.Send((t)=>{IsWorking = false;},null);    //this is for change the visual tree from another thread
                      };
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Then in you XAML code you need to bind the visibility of the image or control to this property, using a BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

I think this is the classic way to do this. Hope works for you...

Comment: I understand that. I had that already implemented. I need that image processing control for UI. How I can make that Image with animation

Comment: You can animate an Image control (with the image you want inside) with a RotateTransform and make it repeat forever (it is a boolean or enum value). Then hide or show that control when ever you want.